# Programmatically generate organizational report in AWS Trusted Advisor

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, rest

I am trying to generate Organizational report in AWS trusted advisor programmatically with Python and later fetch the report for reporting. However, there is no direct API or SDK method available to automate the report generation.

Does someone have any other suggestion on how to generate Organizational report and fetch the report?

**What am I doing?**
Trying to generate Organizational report in AWS trusted advisor programmatically with Python.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
A working solution to generate and fetch Organizational report from AWS trusted advisor.